# Showing blank table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables.

While using joins query when it find the value in another table then it shows values properly. But when if record is not available then entire table's record is not displaying. It means blank table.

My question is: if record is not available for that ID then it should return null values and other details which are present atleast that should display.

Below query is working fine because all the details are present.

```
select bs.strBusinessName
     , bs.strBusinessDescription
     , bs.strCreatedOn
     , am.strAmenitiesName
     , con.strContactOne
  from tblbusinessdetails bs
     , tblamenities am
     , tbloutletamenities oam
     , tbloutletcontactdetails con
 where bs.nBusinessDetailsId = oam.nBusinessDetailsId 
   AND oam.nAmenitiesId = am.nAmenitiesId
   AND bs.nBusinessDetailsId = con.nBusinessDetailsId
   AND bs.nVendorId = 1 
   AND bs.nBusinessDetailsId = 102;
```

But this query showing blank table

```
select bs.strBusinessName
     ,bs.strBusinessDescription,bs.strCreatedOn,
am.strAmenitiesName,
con.strContactOne,
tim.strShiftOneFromTime,tim.strShiftOneToTime
from tblbusinessdetails bs,tblamenities am,tbloutletamenities oam,tbloutletcontactdetails con,tbloutlettimingsdetails tim
where bs.nBusinessDetailsId=oam.nBusinessDetailsId AND oam.nAmenitiesId=am.nAmenitiesId 
AND bs.nBusinessDetailsId=con.nBusinessDetailsId
AND bs.nBusinessDetailsId=tim.nBusinessDetailsId
AND bs.nVendorId=1 AND bs.nBusinessDetailsId=102;
```

Comment: This is a downside of using implicit joins.You should rewrite this using explicit joins or left joins as appropriate,

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` to return null values when there's no row.